# How to remove information about old firing alerts in notification?

Tags: prometheus, alertmanager

When 1 alert is firing, AlertManager sends a notification, then 2nd alert is firing or resolved, AM sends a notification with information about 2 alerts. How to remove information about 1st alert in notification? I set ‘repeat_interval: 24h’ for AM config, but it doesnt help. I use Amazon Prometheus.

Comment: group_by parameter helped

Comment: This is cross-site duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60949623